# Run time error 1004 placing INDEX formula into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic validation list inside an excel template that shows by default the *"user"* that is running the excel file, (using the formula `=INDEX(user; 1)`, user is a `name range` that has the current *"user"* shown first.

Once the the template is completely filled, the sheet gets copied into a new file and the new file get's sent by e-email.

Because the *"user"* changes when the new file gets opened, I needed to paste the values from the validation into the template, just before copying the sheets.

My idea is because the template can get cleared for re-use to have the formulas reentered by macro into cells. I have tried using `Worksheets("template").Range("D3").Formula = "=INDEX(user; 1)"` but I get the `runtime error 1004 application defined or object defined error`.

Please advise. I have presented the broader idea in order to allow alternative solutions for the purpose I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Change the `;` to `,`. VBa is very American English centric.   When VBa puts the formula in the sheet excel will make the change to your local settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to save your *"excel template"* workbook as a *real Excel Template* using the appropriated `FileFormat` value *(*`xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled` *if the template has macros or* `xlOpenXMLTemplate` *if it does not have macros)*.

If saving the template with a procedure you can use these lines:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:="Workbook FullName.xltm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, _
    Password:="If Required", WriteResPassword:="If Required", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    Rem Replace these lines if template has no macros
    'Filename:="Workbook FullName.xltx", _
    'FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplate, _
```

When the user double clicks the workbook template a copy of the original template workbook is opened, leaving the original template intact, so there will be no need to reset the formulas for re-use.

If the template is opened by a procedure, instead of an user's doubleclick then use this line:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Workbook_FullName.xltm", Editable:=True
```

see [Save a workbook or worksheet as a template](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Save-a-workbook-or-worksheet-as-a-template-58C6625A-2C0B-4446-9689-AD8BAEC39E1E), [Save a workbook as a template](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Save-a-workbook-as-a-template-855D15BD-39EC-458B-8AF8-456517A661D7)